# Removing the colon in Time Format and append the values

Tags: sql-server

I am working on a scenario where I need to store the time in the following format:

10:23:56 --> 102356

Is it possible to store the above mentioned format in the **time** datatype column in MS SQL ?

Comment: You cannot store this `102356` integer in `TIME` datatype

Answer (score 2):

That isnt a `time` datatype.

- You either save it as `time` and format the output when query the table.
- Or format the output and save it as string.

Use `RIGHT` to make sure all number are two digits

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(
       RIGHT('00'+ DATEPART(HOUR  , GETDATE()), 2),
       RIGHT('00'+ DATEPART(MINUTE, GETDATE()), 2),
       RIGHT('00'+ DATEPART(SECOND, GETDATE()), 2)
   )
;
```

As mentioned `CONCAT` work only on `2012+` a more generic aproach

```
SELECT 
    RIGHT('00'+ CAST(DATEPART(HOUR  , GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2) ), 2) +
    RIGHT('00'+ CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2) ), 2) +
    RIGHT('00'+ CAST(DATEPART(SECOND, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2) ), 2)
;
```

Comment: `CONCAT` was introduced in `SQL Server 2012` worth mentioning. Prior to that you need to use `+` with appropriate *Casting*

Comment: @MotoGP I was lazy and didnt want do the `CAST`.  Include both version now